# Permission denied because of publickey

Tags: bash, ssh

I just made created a virtual instance on cloud google and I'd like to connect to it in terminal but for some reason I can't. Why doesn't allow me to copy it? And if it exists why the does it deny the permission? Thanks

```
roka@alma:/mnt/c/Users/roka/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub roka@3x.7x.1x.29
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
Enter passphrase for key './id_rsa':

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.

roka@alma:/mnt/c/Users/roka/.ssh$ ssh roka@3x.7x.1x.29
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: The error message explains the problem : "All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system." so no need to copy the key, just ssh in with the key. `ssh -i id_rsa.pub roka@3x.7x.1x.29`

Comment: If I enter id_rsa.pub it asks for the passphrase 3 times then prints Permission denied (publickey). If I enter ssh -i id_rsa roka@3x.7x.1x.29 then it works. So id_rsa is the private key, that's what you meant right?

Comment: yes, I just copied-pasted.

Comment: I'm grateful, thanks very much for your help! My last question: How could I do this from an android application? Copy the private key into it is not secure. Do you have any better idea? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with android ssh applications , but you need to transfer the key somehow. I would plug the phone into the computer and copy the key.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but that's no secure, is it?

Comment: How is it no secure ?

Comment: When it's only me who uses the app it's okay, but if I'd want it to publish, one can look into the apk file and get the private key from it

Comment: That is sort of a different question, but yes you should not make the private key publicly available.